# Restrict post route

Tags: mojolicious

Having this code in a Mojolicious App:

```
my $svc = $authorized->under('/cleaning')->to('Login#has_role', roles_allowed =>  ['office', 'booking', 'reception']);
$svc->post('/new')       ->name('create_svc')->to('Cleaning#create'); 
$svc->get ('/edit/:id')  ->name('edit_svc')  ->to('Cleaning#edit');
$svc->post('/edit/:id')  ->name('update_svc')->to('Cleaning#update');
```

What is the most fundamental and simple way to restrict the `update_svc` route to *office* and *booking*? In other words: All users having the *office* or *booking* role should be able to send the changing post requests whereas the *cleaning* users should only be able to view the form.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution myself:

```
my $svc_read  = $authorized->under('/cleaning')->to('Login#has_role', roles_allowed =>  ['office', 'booking', 'reception']);
my $svc_write = $authorized->under('/cleaning')->to('Login#has_role', roles_allowed =>  ['office', 'booking']);

$svc_write->post('/new')     ->name('create_svc')->to('Cleaning#create'); 
$svc_read ->get('/edit/:id') ->name('edit_svc')  ->to('Cleaning#edit');
$svc_write->post('/edit/:id')->name('update_svc')->to('Cleaning#update');
```

But may be there are more generic solutions which work better, if you have many get/post routes already available in your app.